# lando db-import data.sql > Command error: ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 654: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, wordpress, lando

I am using `lando` for my WordPress local setup.
Lando offers a CLI based database import capability. The steps to use the command are:

```
$ lando start
$ lando db-import data.sql
```

Documentation: https://docs.lando.dev/guides/db-import.html

But, the above command always fails with the following error message:

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 654: MySQL server has gone away.

I went through various articles and all are saying that the above error appears if the SQL file is too big or there is a large query in it. According to their suggestions, I added the following lines in my.cnf file and restarted MySql service.

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
max_packet_size = 128M
```

However, the result is still the same.

I am on `Ubuntu 22.04`

I have at least 9 websites setup at my local use `lando` and none of them have this issue. Which leads me to think that the problem might not be global and may be site specific. Could there be a chance that the database dump got corrupted?

NB: There are several posts in Stack Overflow mentioning the same issue. I tried all workarounds that go with Ubuntu. However, nothing had worked.

Comment: Is there anything indicating a crash or an error in the MySQL Server error log?

Comment: Does the `lando info` command list the db server?